# Can reallocation happen to a vector before the size reaches the reserved capacity?

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose I do `v.reserve(1000000);`
Am I guaranteed no reallocation will happen before the first time `v.size()` is equal to 1000000 ?

Comment: Well, obviously if you do a bulk insert of 1000001 elements. But I assume you meant a single-element insertion.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no reallocation.

It would not be legal because inserting into a `vector` with sufficient capacity does not invalidate iterators (other than the `end` iterator) and references into said `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

From [1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/):

If n is greater than the current vector capacity, the function causes the container to reallocate its storage increasing its capacity to n (or greater).

In all other cases, the function call does not cause a reallocation and the vector capacity is not affected.

where n is the argument of elements to reserve size for.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any new allocations if you don't reach the reserved size.

However you can read [this interesting article](https://www.zerotier.com/blog/2017-05-05-theleak.shtml) about standard library 'optimizations' for your memory.